# Strange paginate_links behavior. First page link is always whatever page I'm on, all other links are correct

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I'm using the following code to generate some pagination:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=5'.'&paged='.$paged);
$big = 999999999;
echo '<div class="pagination">';
echo paginate_links(array(  'base' => '%_%',
                            'format' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link( $big ))),
                            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                            'end_size' =>4,
                            'type' => 'list'));     
    echo '</div>';
```

Its generating my links correctly on the first page, but if I go to any other page everything is still correct except the link for page 1 is always the url of whatever page I am on.  Seems like I'm missing somthing simple, anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Try

```
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
```

**Long answer:**

I took a look at the `paginate_links()` source code ([v3.5.1](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1922)) and there is this line ([#](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1970))

```
$link = str_replace('%_%', 1 == $n ? '' : $format, $base);
```

that is giving you the empty first page link.

With your setup you have `$base = "%_%"` and `$format = "http://example.com/page/%#%/"` so this becomes:

```
$link = str_replace('%_%', 1 == $n ? '' : "http://example.com/page/%#%/", "%_%");
```

where we have two cases:

```
n=1:     $link = str_replace('%_%', '', "%_%");

n>1:     $link = str_replace('%_%', "http://example.com/page/%#%/", "%_%");
```

and after the replacement:

```
n=1:     $link = '';

n>1:     $link = "http://example.com/page/%#%/";
```

Here is an example of the output from `paginate_links()`:

```
<ul class='page-numbers'>
    <li><a class="prev page-numbers" href="http://example.com/page/2/">&laquo; Previous</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href=''>1</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/2/'>2</a></li>
    <li><span class='page-numbers current'>3</span></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/4/'>4</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/5/'>5</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/6/'>6</a></li>
    <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="http://example.com/page/4/">Next &raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you use instead ([#](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Examples)):

```
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
```

then you get:

```
$link = str_replace('%_%', 1 == $n ? '' : "?paged=%#%", "http://example.com/page/%#%");
```

Since no replacement will take place

```
$link = "http://example.com/page/%#%";
```

in both cases (n=1 and n>1) and you have a non empty first page link with the output of `paginate_links()`:

```
<ul class='page-numbers'>
    <li><a class="prev page-numbers" href="http://example.com/page/2/">&laquo; Previous</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/1/'>1</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/2/'>2</a></li>
    <li><span class='page-numbers current'>3</span></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/4/'>4</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/5/'>5</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/6/'>6</a></li>
    <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="http://example.com/page/4/">Next &raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

To have a non empty first page link it looks like  `$format` can be any string as long as `$base` doesn't include the string `"%_%"`, i.e. these should work fine:

```
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'format' => 'page/%#%',
'format' => 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf',
```

If you don't use permalinks, then the example in ([#](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Examples)) will also give you non empty first page link since

```
$link = str_replace('%_%', 1 == $n ? '' : "?paged=%#%", "http://example.com/?paged=%#%");
```

with replacements.

Comment: That did the trick.  I don't understand why they would need to put a special situation for page 1 though...nice catch on the source.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks birgire for help. I'm sharing the result of my paginate_links() which are working with custom taxonomy pages exactly as I need.

Hope this will help someone to fix it as quick as possible.

So here it is:

```
if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
}
global $paged;
if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
}
if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
}        
    $pagination_args = array(
     'base'            => str_replace('%_%', 1 == $paged ? '' : "?page=%#%", "?page=%#%"),
     'format'          => '?page=%#%',
     'total'           => $numpages,
     'current'         => $paged,
     'show_all'        => False,
     'end_size'        => 1,
     'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
     'prev_next'       => True,
     'prev_text'       => __('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'),
     'next_text'       => __('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'),
     'type'            => 'list',
     'add_args'        => false,
     'add_fragment'    => ''
    );

$paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'><ul>";
    echo $paginate_links;
    echo "</ul></nav>";
}
```

Comment: If you want to support custom formats, you cannot use the 'format' because that only gets used using `%_%`.

Instead, omit format and do this:
`'base' => str_replace('%_%', 1 == $paged ? '' : "?page=%#%", '?' . $custom_format .  '=%#%'),`
Define `$custom_format` first.

Also note, the `paged` format does NOT work on posts because it is actually not intended for this. Also as of WP 5.5 NEITHER of both will work anymore because of https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50976#comment:22 (of course "it is obvious", pun intended, because even they own doc suggests it will work)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on a same problem and found out that I can replace:

```
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
```

with:

```
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
```

So just renamed 'paged' >'page' in query var and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Bobz solution worked for me:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { 
    $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page'); 
} else { 
    $paged = 1; 
}
```

```
echo paginate_links(array(
    'current' => $paged,
    'prev_text' => __('Anterior'),
    'next_text' => __('Siguiente'),
    'total' => $variable->max_num_pages
));
```